# Best container/compressor for nesting

Tags: tar, compression, zip, 7zip

Is there a format, such as 7zip, zip, tar.gz etc that that 'glues' pre-compressed folders together quickly? At the moment, it appears that archiving pre-compressed files/folders has very little benefit when compressing up the parent directory.

I don't care which format I use or compression rates, so much as ensuring that the end result is a single file.

Answer (score 1):

gnu **tar** without the "z" option glues the file without compression, files are stacked into the **tar** archive. Recovery of a single file is slow due to sequential read

formats like **rar** or **zip** use file indexing to permit quick recovery, these formats have option to disable compression.